# Отрицание в регулярных выражениях

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка вот такого вида:

> `#http\:\/\/domain\.ru\/post\/(.+?)\#comment_(\d+)#i`

Прекрасно разбирает строки вида:

> `http://domain.ru/post/25#comment_12`

А вот с таким возникает проблема:

> `[url=http://domain.ru/post/25#comment_12]123456[/url]`

Т.к. для bb кода url есть своя регулярка, которая обрабатывается отдельно. Как можно модифицировать первую регулярку, чтобы она забирала только ссылки, которые находятся вне "[url=]"?

Пытался использовать то, что пишут на форумах, но операторы для отрицания отказываются работать:

> ```
> #[^(\[url=)]http\:\/\/domain\.ru\/post\/(.+?)\#comment_(\d+)#i
>
> #(?!\[url=)http\:\/\/domain\.ru\/post\/(.+?)\#comment_(\d+)#i
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так

```
$re = '~(?<!\[url=)http:/domain\.ru/post/(.+?)#comment_(\d+)~i'; 
$str = "[url=http://domain.ru/post/25#comment_12]123456[/url]\nhttp://domain.ru/post/25#comment_12";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[Manual php Утверждения](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.assertions.php)